# error: cannot find symbol method crossFade() in 4.7.1

Tags: android, android-glide

Before anyone duplicate it. I was using the below code before in v3.7.0 of glide. Now when I have updated it to 4.7.1 it is showing the error: cannot find symbol method crossFade().

I have searched in different places but could not get the code work.

```
Glide.with(this)
                    .load(uriProfileImage)
                    .crossFade()
                    .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(EditProfile.this))
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(changeImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Glide myself, but based on [this v4 documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html) it looks like you need to use a transition and a `TransitionOptions` to specify a cross-fade, so your code would look *something* like this:

```
import static com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.BitmapTransitionOptions.withCrossFade;

...

Glide.with(this)
    .load(uriProfileImage)
    .transition(withCrossFade())
    .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(EditProfile.this))
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(changeImage);
```

(I've assumed you want a `BitmapTransitionOptions` rather than `DrawableTransitionOptions` here, given the `bitmapTransform` call.)

You should probably also read the ["common errors"](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transitions.html#common-errors) section about cross-fades too.

Comment: then it says: Cannot resolve method 'bitmapTransform()'

Comment: @AshishYadav: You may need to move the transition part after the other parts then. (As I have no experience with Glide, you'll need to do further research yourself. Basically I've shown that what was a separate method call before is now something to be specified as a transition.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, use old version solve the problem.
 **implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'** than implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' which is the last version